# Display more than 40,000 bars in EChart GL

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm trying to display a large amount of data in a 3d EChart. At first I used a [scatter3D type](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option-gl.html#series-scatter3D), which worked fine, but I thought that using a [bar3D chart](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option-gl.html#series-bar3D) would be more clear. Then I noticed that if I exceed 40,000 instances of data the chart would appear empty. Is there a way to overpass this limit?

40,000 random points:

[image: 40,000 random points]

40,001 random points:

[image: 40,001 random points]

No errors nor logs are displayed in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out the source of
this issue, that's rather puzzling once one realizes that
OP's observation is exactly verified, and it's not depending on hardware or WebGL limitations.

Let me start with the solution: to increase the number of bars that are drawn from the default limit of 40000, you multiply by a (> 1) factor the following options:
`grid3D.boxWidth`, `grid3D.boxHeight`, `grid3D.boxDepth` and
`grid3D.viewControl.distance`, e.g.,

```js
{
    grid3D: {
        boxWidth: 150,   // default is 100
        boxHeight: 150,  // default is 100
        boxDepth: 150,   // default is 100
        viewControl:{
            distance: 300 // default is 200
        }
        // other grid3D options .........
    }
}
```

The multiplicative factor being 1.5, the number of bars will increase from 40_000 (200x200) to 90_000 (300x300). Only `boxWidth` and `boxHeight` are essential; the others are increased to keep the initial viewport unchanged.

And now the explanation: with the default settings, the width and
the depth of each bar *becomes zero* if you have more than 40000 data points. So there are actually 40001+ bars processed and sent to rendering, but there's nothing visible because of the zero sizes.

The problem is that, if x axis and y axis are value axes, the `barWidth` and `barDepth` are calculated using:

```js
barWidth = Math.round(size[0] / Math.sqrt(data.count())) * 0.6;
barDepth = Math.round(size[1] / Math.sqrt(data.count())) * 0.6;
```

that can be found in the source code at
[cartesian3DLayout.js L30](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-gl/blob/2.0.8/src/chart/bar3D/cartesian3DLayout.js#L30)
and [L36](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-gl/blob/2.0.8/src/chart/bar3D/cartesian3DLayout.js#L36).
There `size[0]` is initialized to `boxWidth` and `size[1]` to `boxHeight`,
as per [grid3DCreator.js L38](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-gl/blob/2.0.8/src/coord/grid3DCreator.js#L38).

Thus, the mathematical condition for the number of bars that are rendered
(with all sizes > 0) is:

```js
data.count() <= (2 * Math.min(boxWidth, boxHeight)) ** 2
```

which renders 40000 for box sizes of 100.

I was initially inclined to consider this a bug, but I'd say now that
there are probably good reasons for these choices.